# Unable to use "oninput" event in JSP. What are the alternatives?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jsp, web-applications

I am working on a JSP page that contains an input box that takes in a date. I want to convert that time into another timezone and autofill the other input box. I tried to do this by using oninput event to call a JS function but when I change the input in the first input box, nothing appears in the second input box accordingly. I am new to JSP and JS. I am wondering what am I doing wrong here. What is the right way to implement such a function.

**My JSP:**

```
<tr>
<td>Final Date</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="finalDate" id="datepicker" oninput="convertTime('datepicker', 'CST')"/>
</td>
<td>CST</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="cstTime" id="CST" />
</td>
```

**My JS:**

```
function convertTime(iID, oID) {
var LA    = moment.tz(document.getElementById(iID).value, "America/Los_Angeles");
var PST = new Date(LA);

document.getElementById(oID).value = PST.toLocaleString('en-GB', { timeZone: 'CST' });
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener